# jQuery AJAX response error (FF and Safari not working)

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

In Safari and Firefox, the response part of the code is not working (i.e. from PHP-->Ajax-->jQuery). The variables definitely make it to the PHP fine (tested using `mail()` ), so it's probably some small error on my behalf!

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: postData,
    url: "http://www.kudiclub.com/test/login/?loginsub",
    success: function(data){
        if(data.success==false){
            $("#login .error").html(data.reply).show();
            $("#login-email").val(data.email);
            $("#password").val("");
        }else{
            window.location = data.ref;
        }
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$data = array('success' => false, 'reply' => 'Username and password did not match.', 'email' => $email);
print json_encode($data);
return;
```

Hoping somebody can help. Thanks, Nick.

**SOLUTION**

After much fiddling about, it turns out that it doesn't see a full URL as a relative path. Changing the `url` to `'/test/login/?loginsub'` did the trick.

Comment: Are you saying the `success` function doesn't get called at all, or it goes to the wrong branch of the if/else? (Also, you mention two specific browsers - does that mean you've tried other browsers where it worked, or you've not tried other browsers?)

Comment: Chrome and IE both work. success() doesn't get called at all in FF/Safari, error() *does* get called in them.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the JSON response- but i'm clueless as to what!

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem, but if `error()` _does_ get called what error is received? Use the parameters passed to `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` and/or your browser's dev tools to find out...

Comment: Is it possible the browser is getting confused with the `data` in your `ajax` call and the `data` as the parameter in your `success` function?

Comment: No SenorAmor, "data" is the return variable default set by jQuery $.ajax()

Comment: So what is [object Object] error?  You should be able to set a breakpoint in your error callback in Chrome of Firefox using their various dev tools, and then see what you're getting back as an error.  It will have more useful information than [object Object].

Comment: Yes, try `console.dir(errorThrown)` or `console.log(errorThrown)`...

Comment: Firefox Dev Tools registers no error: `[22:50:54.780] POST http://www.kudiclub.com/test/login/?loginsub [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 170ms]`

Comment: Any clues how to fix this based on the above then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server says: Content-Type: text/html. Is not a json document (application/json).

```
http://www.kudiclub.com/test/login/?loginsub

GET /test/login/?loginsub HTTP/1.1
Host: www.kudiclub.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: PHPSESSID=060b8210adfb3c67ff792b9471c7fa1c
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 02 Aug 2012 22:12:10 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=200
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: I saw that. How can this be used to fix the problem? Edit: you have taken the http header from the php file, not the JavaScript file in which the issue lies...

Comment: In the php code of the web server: <?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); ?> in first line. Firefox and safary dont work by safety reasons, ie are unsure why it works.

Comment: After adding that line, nothing has changed. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check your code. Safari, Firefox, PHP and jQuery are not guilty. Test with firebug.